# Is there an established notation for $A_1A_2\dots A_n$, a product of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, numerical-linear-algebra

I've taken a course or two in numerical analysis and often several matrices in a family- say $A_i\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m},1\le i\le n$- need to be multiplied. I haven't encountered an established notation for this, so I often defined and used the usual notation for products with success:
$$
A_1 A_2\dots A_{n-1}A_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}A_k
$$If instead we are multiplying in the opposite order, one could just 'flip' the product:
$$
A_n A_{n-1}\dots A_2 A_1 = \coprod_{k=1}^{n} A_k \left(=\prod_{k=1}^{n}A_{n+1-k}\right)
$$Is there a more conventional notation for this procedure?

Comment: Your notation - at least in this font - is rather hard to differentiate for those of us whose eyes are not as flexible as they used to be. The upside-down $\Pi$ is also used to represent disjoint union, but that isn't of much concern here. Personally, I prefer $\prod_{k=1}^n A_{n+1-k}$ which doesn't require the reader to learn yet another highly specialized notation.

Comment: Here are two ideas:  use a transpose to reverse the order $\,\Big(\prod_{k=1}^n A_k^T\Big)^T\,$ or swap the limits as you would with an integral $\,\prod_{k=n}^1 A_k\;$

Comment: Between the two, I still prefer the $n+1-k$ indexing, but it is minor either way. Greg's other notation is nice, but might be confusing for a newbie.

Comment: @PaulSinclair's point is well made.  Whatever notation you end up using, be sure to comment on its meaning when you introduce it, and again when you first use it in earnest.

Comment: In the book "Nonhomogeneous Matrix Products" by Hartfiel, he uses the notation $\prod_{k=1}^\infty A_k = \ldots A_{k+1}A_k\ldots A_1$ to denote infinite "left" products, and the same notation for $\prod_{k=1}^\infty A_k = A_1\ldots A_{k}A_{k+1}\ldots$, which he calls a "right" product. So, I don't think there is a conventional way, and you may have to define it prior to using it. Then there is also the notation $\prod_{A\in{\mathcal{A}}} A$, where an arbitrary matrix is picked from the family $\mathcal{A}$ to form an infinite product.

Comment: @bodil but how does he distinguish them? Having an ambiguous notation isn't much better than having no notation at all. I like $\prod_{k=1}^{n}A_{n+1-k}$ or $\left(\prod_{k=1}^n A_k^T\right)^T$ for the 'left' product.

Comment: @Integrand It's very annoying indeed, but he assumes throughout the rest of the book that the product is left, unless stated otherwise. In that case, $\prod_{k=1}^nA_{n+1-k}$ is indeed a solution to represent finite right products, but not infinite.

Comment: @bodil I personally don't like deviating from $\prod_{k=1}^n A_k$ to denote the left product, and I would just stick to it unless I really need a right product, in which case I would just write out $A_1A_2\ldots A_n$. The first notation that greg proposes can be a bit cumbersome to write, while the second can easily be overlooked, leading to mistakes, IMO.

Comment: Another point: $A_1A_2\dots A_n$ is 15 characters to type in $\LaTeX$ and $\prod_{k=1}^nA_k$ is 16, and every other suggested notation is even longer. So maybe it's better to stick with the good old $\dots$?

Comment: In context, both $A_1 \cdots A_n$ and $A_n \cdots A_1$ should make sense, and be short and unambiguous even for the uninitiated reader.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against $\coprod$; products and coproducts are "categorical opposites", and it just seems bound to cause confusion to muddy the waters with the coproduct symbol. I'll give another vote for $\prod_{k=n}^1 A_k$ in the finite case, but $\prod_{k=1}^n A_{n+1-k}$ is probably technically clearest. Note that $\prod_{k=\infty}^1 A_k = \cdots A_2 A_1$ is probably the only reasonable interpretation, though it's a bit confusing. Another option is $(A_i \prod_{k=1}^n) = A_n \cdots A_1$ and $(A_i \prod_{k=1}^\infty) = \cdots A_2 A_1$. It's cute and flexible, but perhaps confusing.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I have taught enough calculus to have flashbacks about terms outside operators, or terms floating in space (not a fan of Einstein notation either). Probably won't adopt the second notation.

Comment: @NikitaSkybytskyi true, but if the $A_i$ are of certain forms it might make sense (for instance, $A_i = B_i + \lambda_i I$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion:

- In contrast to sigma/product notation, it seems $A_1\dots A_n$ or $A_n\dots A_1$ are generally seen as acceptable and clear.
- Using bodil's terminology of left/right products, $\prod_{k=1}^{n} A_k$ is probably an acceptable way to write the left product $ A_n\dots A_1$, even if it doesn't save too many characters. However, if the $A_i$ have a special form, such as $A_i = B_i +\lambda_i I$, the product notation might be better.
- Regarding right products, the most common option seems to be either the standard dot-dot-dot notation or $\prod_{k=1}^{n} A_{n-k+1}$. Several people also suggested swapping the limits, viz. $\prod_{k=n}^{1} A_k$. greg had another suggestion: $A_1\cdots A_n = \left(\prod _{k=1}^{n}A_k^T\right)^T$. $\coprod$ was not well-received.